# Fill background of children accordingly to parent mousover

Tags: javascript, css

I have three bars which need to be filled based on a percentage

```
<div class="bars" style="width:0%; background-color: red;">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

The width changes based on mouseover of the .bars element like this

```
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (ev) {
    var volume = document.getElementsByClassName('.bars')[0],
       position = ev.clientX - volume.offsetLeft,
       percentage = 100 * position / volume.clientWidth;

    volume.style.width = percentage + '%';
});
```

css

```
.bars {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
.bar {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    &.-one {
        height: 15px;
        width: 9px;
        left: 0;
    }
    &.-two {
        height: 20px;
        width: 9px;
        left: 10px;
    }
    &.-three {
        height: 25px;
        width: 9px;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Summary:
I want to fill each bar with the background color of the parent based on the mouseover percentage, without ignoring the space between the bars and the height of the bars, so the parent should have by matter of speaking transparant background and the bars should only be visible qua background.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I already posted my answer but now you edited your question and it looks like the bars are vertical, am I right?

Comment: Ah yes and there is supposed to be space between them, i'll fix that. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make this type of effect using gradient backgrounds. Let's say you want to fill the bar using the color blue and the rest of the bar will be yellow. (You replace with the color you want)

```js
var percentage = 30;  // 30%
var bar = ...         // get the bar element

bar.style.background = `linear-gradient(to top, blue 0%, blue ${percentage}%, yellow ${percentage}%, yellow 100%)`
```